# how to get the PageFormat from a Java.awt.print.PrinterJob

Tags: java, swing, printing, dimensions

I'm trying to use the PageFormat information to modify my javax.swing based printout prior to printing it.  I am stumped as to how I can get the PageFormat from the PrintJob (which is obtained using getPrinterJob() and printDialog()).  I know there is the getPageFormat method, but I can't figure out how to get the PrintRequestAttributeSet (which is not the printJob.getPrintService().getPrintAttributes()).  Honestly, all I really want to know is the width and height of the page.  Any ideas on how I can do that?  Thanks.

Comment: that's the problem, I can't get the PageFormat for the print job.

Answer (score 2):

The approach of running a "fake" print job does NOT work, at least in the long run. I tried it. At first it worked great ... then some customers started reporting strange behaviors.

Turns out, with **some** printers and some configurations, even "fake" jobs cause activity at the printer. No document pages printed, but queue activity, job header pages, and sometimes a bit of garbage output (as I recall). The bogus queue entries were enough to interfere with normal printing, in some cases, and confusing to the user.

Yes, getting the PageFormat ahead of time was a pain.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If you just need the page width and height, I think PageFormat.getImageableWidth() and
PageFormat.getImageableHeight() are what you're looking for.</strike>

Sorry, that's not what you wanted. How about this for a hack:

```
printable.setFakeJob(true);
job.print();
printable.setFakeJob(false);
job.print();
```

and in your printable,

```
public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex) {
    if (isFakeJob()) {
        /* use passed-in PageFormat to set up whatever you need to set up */
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    } else {
        /* do your actual printing */
    }
}
```

Not pretty, admittedly.

Comment: that's the problem, I can't get the PageFormat for the print job.

Comment: Sorry, managed to misread your question! I understand now, I think: you want to get the page size *before* your Printable.print(Graphics, PageFormat, int) method is called back. Unfortunately I can't see a way to do it either: PrinterJob doesn't seem to let you access the choices the user makes in the print dialog without calling PrinterJob.print().

I have an idea for a hack which I'll post as another answer.